# Link button doesn't insert URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

If I'm using the WP Editor post editor and highlight some text, then click the 'link' button and fill in a URL, when I'm done, the link always looks like this:

```
<a href="undefined" title="undefined">
```

With the built-in editor, the URL is filled in.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean, you're using some editor plugin?

Comment: yes i am using WP Editor plugin. If i deactivate the plugin then ' link ' button is working fine . But when i activate the plugin , then  click the 'link' button and fill in a URL ,the link always looks like this:<a href="undefined" title="undefined">

Comment: you would need to update `WP Editor plugin` or contact with the author.

Comment: Does the plugin and Wordpress are both up to date?

Comment: Yes plugin and Wordpress are both up to date.

Comment: Please suggest me what should i do.